# Choice of color for graphs with filled area

Tags: data-analysis

I am writing an article and the central results are summarized in a graph so I want it to be very beautiful and physically intuitive. It has 3 regions in which a certain quantity is conserved, partially conserved or not conserved so I want them to be respectively green, yellow/orange and red. The problem is that I can't find a good combination of colors... Maybe someone has done something of similar before and can give some suggestion.. I post here my figure:

[image]

Maybe it is not the right place where ask this question but I can not find a more appropriate Stack Exchange site to post it...

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not is about physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that green, red and yellow/orange do not intuitively suggest different levels of conservation. In addition to that yellow/orange and red have a very poor contrast with each other. Here's what I suggest:

In the full conserved region--> take blue
In the partially conserved region--> take a much lighter shade the same kind of blue
In non-conserved region --> take white

The key to good making pretty presentations and related stuff is minimalism and clarity.